# linq query to element w/o foreach

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I need some help with LINQ and XML. I've read numerous articles but just can't seem to find what I'm looking for as most people are looping through results to get values.  I have the following XML and I need to access a specific element based first on the *section name* and then on the *control id*.

```
<formData>
    <section name="SectionA">
        <control id="Textbox1" type="TextBox">
            <value>Value1</value>
        </control>
        <control id="Textbox2" type="TextBox">
            <value>Value2</value>
        </control>
        <control id="Textbox3" type="TextBox">
            <value>Value2</value>
        </control>
    </section>
    <section name="SectionB" />
    <section name="SectionC" />
    <section name="SectionD" />
    <section name="SectionE" />
</formData>
```

I'm using the following code to get the element I need.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> fields = xDocument.Element("formData").Elements("section")
        .Where(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "SectionA")
        .Single()
        .Elements("control")
        .Where(f => f.Attribute("id").Value == "Control1");
```

Which results in the following element:

```
<control id="Textbox1" type="TextBox">
    <value>Value1</value>
</control>
```

However, that's as far as I can get...  I need three separate values, the ID, the TYPE and the Value.  How do I go about this without using foreach or nested foreach loops?

Thank you

Comment: So using the anonymous types, I can access those fields with:

*fields.ElementAt(0)*  OR  *fields.FirstOrDefault()* or is there a better way?  Thanks Mike

Comment: With anonymous types, the type of fields would be IEnumerable<AnonymousType>.  To access each field, you could go through each control and access the Id, Type, and Value properties.  If you only want the first one, call fields.FirstOrDefault() to get the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would be ok using anonymous types, you could do this:

```
var fields = xDocument.Element("formData").Elements("section")
    .Where(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "SectionA")
    .Single()
    .Elements("control")
    .Where(f => f.Attribute("id").Value == "Control1").Select( f => new
{
     Id = f.Attribute("id"),
     Type = f.Attribute("type"),
     Value = f.Element("value").Value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xdoc.Descendants("section")
    .Where(m => m.Attribute("name").Value == "SectionA")
    .Single()
    .Descendants("control")
    .Where(f => f.Attribute("id").Value == "Textbox1")
    .Select(f => new 
                   { Id = f.Attribute("id").Value, 
                     Type = f.Attribute("type").Value, 
                     Value = f.Element("value").Value } );
```

However I'd be more inclined to use XPath for the first half:

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements(@"//section[@name=""SectionA""]/control[@id=""Textbox1""]")
    .Select(f => new 
                   { Id = f.Attribute("id").Value, 
                     Type = f.Attribute("type").Value, 
                     Value = f.Element("value").Value } );
```